# How to link to other internal sites when the list where the links are place is generated with a map function?

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, hyperlink

I just started to work with react and just getting by. Right now I am using a react website template and working on a menu list. Therefore, each menu-point (slide) should link to an individual site on my project. The thing is that the list is populated with a map function and therefore I just have one link. My question now is, where or how can I insert different links to different internal sites?

Right now all the slides point to the same page: /project-details2/project-details2-dark

```
{ShowcassesFullScreenData.map((slide) => (
          <SwiperSlide key={slide.id} className="swiper-slide">
            <div className="full-width">
              <div
                className="bg-img valign"
                style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${slide.image})` }}
                data-overlay-dark="1"
              >
                <div className="caption ontop valign">
                  <div className="o-hidden">
                    <h1 data-swiper-parallax="-2000">
                      <Link
                        href={`/project-details2/project-details2-dark`}
                        passHref
                      >
                        <a>
                          <div className="stroke">{slide.title.first}</div>
                          <span>{slide.title.second}</span>
                        </a>
                      </Link>
                    </h1>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="copy-cap valign">
                  <div className="cap">
                    <h1 data-swiper-parallax="-2000">
                      <Link
                        href={`/project-details2/project-details2-dark`}
                        passHref
                      >
                        <a>
                          <div className="stroke">{slide.title.first}</div>
                          <span>{slide.title.second}</span>
                        </a>
                      </Link>
                    </h1>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </SwiperSlide>
        ))}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "an individual site on my project" - you mean this project you are working on or some other external project?

Comment: I mean the project I am working on. I dont know where to insert the link to different pages. For example if id like to link to "Blog 1", "Blog 2" and "Blog 3" I would need to link to three different pages. However in the code example above I only can link to one (<Link href={`/project-details2/project-details2-dark`} passHref>). My question is where or how can I link to various pages. Hope its clearer what I mean

Answer (score 0):

The solution you need is called "routing". There are many solutions to this but I recommend using popular package React Router (https://reactrouter.com/)

```
export default function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Bookkeeper</h1>
            <nav>
                <Link to="/invoices">Invoices</Link> |{" "}
                <Link to="/expenses">Expenses</Link>
            </nav>
            <Outlet/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

or the Next.js framework (https://nextjs.org/)

```
export default function Home() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <Head>
                <title>Create Next App</title>
                <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
            </Head>

            <main>
                <h1 className="title">
                    Read{' '}
                    <Link href="/posts/first-post">
                        <a>this page!</a>
                    </Link>
                </h1>
            </main>
        </div>
    )
}
```